# Return variable in .executeQueryAsync

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have this code which alert the informations i want but i don't know how to modify this to display my select list, i just need to know how can i change this code and replace `alert(listItemInfo);` by `return listItemInfo;` to display my custom list instead of the default list of SharePoint

```
var lookupSample = lookupSample || {};
var siteUrl = '/sites/studentday/bat/testJS';

lookupSample.CustomizeFieldRendering = function() {
  // Intialize the variables for overrides objects
  var overrideCtx = {
    Templates: {
      Fields: {
        'Supplier': {
          'NewForm': ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(lookupSample.singleLookupValue, "sp.js")
        }
      }
    }
  };
  // Register the override of the field
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}

lookupSample.singleLookupValue = function(ctx) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Suppliers');
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><GroupBy><FieldRef Name = "Category"/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name = "Title"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
  this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  clientContext.load(collListItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
  var listItemInfo = [];
  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
  var tempo = '';
  listItemInfo.push('<select id="DdList" style="width: 200px;">');
  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    if (tempo == oListItem.get_item('Category')) {
      listItemInfo.push('\n    <option value ="' + oListItem.get_id() + '">' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</option>');
    } else {
      if (tempo != "") {
        listItemInfo.push('\n  </optgroup>');
      }
      listItemInfo.push('\n  <optgroup label ="' + oListItem.get_item('Category') + '">');
      listItemInfo.push('\n    <option value ="' + oListItem.get_id() + '">' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</option>');
      tempo = oListItem.get_item('Category');
    }
  }
  listItemInfo.push('\n  </optgroup>');
  listItemInfo.push('\n</select>');
  alert(listItemInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  listItemInfo.push('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

lookupSample.CustomizeFieldRendering();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly return a value from an asynchronous function.

Instead of returning a value at the end of the async function, write a new function to do whatever it is you were going to do with that return value, and call that function.

For example, instead of this:

```
var asyncResult = asyncDoSomething();
doSomethingWithResult(asyncResult); // WRONG

function asyncDoSomething(){
    var something;
    // logic here
    return something;
}
```

...follow this pattern:

```
asyncDoSomething();
// no more code should be executed in this context after calling async function

function asyncDoSomething(){
    var something;
    // logic here
    doSomethingWithResult(something); // RIGHT: logic moved forward
}
```

Don't put additional lines of code within the same scope subsequent to invoking the asynchronous function.

Instead, pass that logic forward, which may mean embedding it into the asynchronous function or (more often) passing a callback function to the asynchronous function for it to invoke when it's done with whatever it does.

Modern libraries often work around this pattern by having asynchronous functions accept two parameters that indicate which functions to invoke upon completion. `executeQueryAsync` for example has two parameters: a function to execute if it succeeds and a function to execute on failure.

JavaScript "promises" work similarly, with each promise object allowing you to specify functions to invoke when the promise is returned (defined through the `then()` function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

In fact, i need to retrieve the listItemInfo variable and put it instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(lookupSample.singleLookupValue, "sp.js")
`

Cause i need to display this select list at a specific place in my NewForm.

I can use promises but i don't know how it works and i tried to apply a promises for my code but it doesn't work.